# pandas dataframe, multiply column values using a dict

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
[in]: data[['currency','value']].sample(10).to_clipboard

[out]
index   currency         value
PIRC.MI      EUR  4.944000e+09
DHIL         USD  5.088264e+08
BBZA.DE      EUR  3.969099e+09
MUR          USD  2.572464e+09
CTEC         USD           NaN
VEA          USD           NaN
KIE          USD           NaN
GLO          USD  4.115056e+08
ET           USD  2.145219e+10
FTV          USD  2.445958e+10
```

and a dict, containing exchange rates for the various currencies (I need to compare them)

```
conversions= {'HKD': 0.13, 
             'EUR': 1.21,
             'GBP': 1.39,
              'USD': 1.0
             }
```

I need to multiply the values of all the currency rows by the corresponding exchange rate in the dict.

for example: all the 'EUR' currency rows by the corresponding 'EUR' exchange rate in the dict, and the same for all the currencies appearing in the dataframe.

I though of iterating with a for through all the items in the dict, but I'm sure pandas support a way better and easier way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
data['currency'].map(conversions).mul(data['value'])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df["result"] = df.currency.map(conversions) * df.value
```

If you look at `df.currency.map(conversions)`, it is

```
0    1.21
1    1.00
2    1.21
3    1.00
4    1.00
5    1.00
6    1.00
7    1.00
8    1.00
9    1.00
```

i.e. it has the multipliers. Then we multiply it by `df.value` column.

Answer (score 2):

```
data['rate'] = data['currency'].map(conversions) 
data['value'] = data['rate'] * data['value']
```